# Changing line height in ACE editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

How do you change line height of ace editor?

[image]

Is there any API to do that? also increasing the line height should also increase the gutter height and cursor height as well, but from their documentation it seems missing.

Though i wrote this with no luck,

```
editor.setOptions({
    lineHeight: "40px"
});
```

I did some CSS hack, but again it breaks the editor layout

```
div.ace_gutter-cell, div.ace_line {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height: 20px !important; 
    /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
editor.container.style.lineHeight = 2
editor.renderer.updateFontSize()
```

similar to what fontSize option does https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.3/lib/ace/virtual_renderer.js#L1703-L1710

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change the `line-height` property in css for the autocomplete popup container.

```
.ace_editor.ace_autocomplete {
    line-height: 36px;
}
```

The above code will make the dropdown option has height of 36px.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the font size will change the line height including the cursor and the gutter.

```
editor.setOptions({
        fontSize: "20px"    
    });
```

Comment: No no,, thats a different thing .... i need to change the `top-line-height` and `bottom-line-height`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to globally set the `fontSize` for every `ace-editor` instance in your app, then you can use

```
    ace.config.set('basePath', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.9/');
    ace.config.set('fontSize', '25px');
    var htmlEditor = ace.edit("html-editor");
```

Comment: the problem with all the solutions is that the tokens stay the same size

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```css
.ace_editor,
.ace_editor * {
    line-height: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

Or, `editor.container.style.lineHeight = 2.5;`